# How can i create a pop up box with two links like "quit" and "back";

Tags: php

Iam creating a multiple choice question paper, how can i create a pop up box when a user decides to quit exam, for him to quit or back with question paper? I am totally a beginner, Thankfull to any help...

Answer (score 1):

Really simple solution:

```
<a href="path/to/redirect" 
   onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to quit?');">Quit</a>
```

The great thing about this is that if the user has JavaScript disabled (unlikely, but possible), the link will still work without the prompt.

Comment: <?php
function promptExit() {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to quit?"))
  {
      window.location.href = "Quit.php";
    }
}

?>
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="promptExit();">Quit</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This is **JavaScript** code, not PHP, it runs within the browser, not on the server.

Comment: @user2779363 see my edited answer, just copy and paste that in to your HTML code.

Comment: @user2779363 Please 'accept' the answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need HTML, CSS and Javascript for that, you can't do that with PHP. PHP only runs on the Server, not on the Client. But there are Frameworks which helps you, like Bootstrap.
http://getbootstrap.com/
And here the Popups: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: OP didn't mention PHP and suggesting he/she should use bootstrap as an answer to this question is not helpful at all.

Comment: I thought as a beginner it is easier to use Bootstrap, than write the javascript on his own.

Comment: Consider this: Does what you posted as an answer answer the question?